# Ho to abort a command in Ubuntu(16.04), where CTRL+C I am already using for copying?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am currently using CTRL+C and CTRL+V for copy and paste respectively in Ubuntu (16.04). So in this case, how can I terminate /abort a command in Terminal.

NOTE: The control+C does not work for me neither quit() or Exit().

Please advise.

Comment: `CTRL+\ ` (control+backslash) should work.  Or `CTRL+Z` should suspend the command and give you a shell prompt, at which point you can use the `kill` command to terminate the suspended command.  It's really not a good idea to remap `CTRL-C`. If you absolutely have to do that then you can designate some other key to replace it. Running, for instance, `stty intr '^k'` will cause `CTRL+K` to become the program interrupt key.  Run `man stty` for details, run `stty -a` to see all of the current terminal management key combinations.

Comment: Thanks, CTRL+Z is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default terminal (`gnome-terminal`) uses Ctrl+Shift+c and Ctrl+Shift+v for exactly this reason. If you are in a bash prompt (unclear from context here), you can quit by writing `exit`.

Comment: I am using gnome-terminal only. Also tried using CTRL+C to abort an operation and come back to new shell prompt when (Ctrl+Shift+C) was being used for copying, but that too didnt work.